# Remove character in comma separated string header and its values

Tags: php

I have a comma separated string stored in a column of data type blob ,with values as given below.

```
date,time,A,B,C,D
11/31/2013,11:00,20,17,18,11
12/31/2013,14:00,18,16,18,14
10/31/2013,17:00,15,17,10,22
09/31/2013,19:00,19,17,20,17
```

I want the string parsed and the string containing date and time removed corresonding to its values finally i require it like this

```
A,B,C,D
20,17,18,11
18,16,18,14
15,17,10,22
19,17,20,17
```

I tried using

```
$exp = explode(',',$arr[0]);
$arrayOfReplacements = array(':' => '','/'=>'');
$clean = strtr($arr[0], $arrayOfReplacements);
print_r($clean);
```

it needs to remove the date,time and its values also.
what more needs to be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$arr[0]` contains the comma separated values:

```
echo join(',', array_slice(explode(',', $arr[0]), 2));
```

See also: [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice)

Alternatively, use `substr()` with `strpos()`:

```
echo substr($arr[0], strpos($arr[0], ',', strpos($arr[0], ',') + 1) + 1);
```

The above assumes that the format of the blob column can be trusted to have at least two commas.

If the format of date and time columns is not going to change, it can be further simplified:

```
echo substr($arr[0], 17);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
$exp = explode(',',$arr[0]);
array_shift($exp);
array_shift($exp);
$output = implode(',',$exp);
```